# How to disable localization for facebook like button

Tags: facebook, localization, facebook-like

Facebook like button looks like "Мне нравится" on my russuin windows. How to disable this behavior? I want to see the same button on all browser and platfroms.

Answer (score 2):

the language is set in the code (in this case 'en_US'):

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=XXXXXXXXX&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
```

here's a list of all language codes:

[facebook locales](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Locales)

yours is probably ru_RU so replace that with the code for your preferred language

Answer (score 1):

Facebook locales follow [ISO language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967365/how-to-disable-localization-for-facebook-like-button/6738186#6738186) and [country codes](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/english_country_names_and_code_elements.htm) respectively, concatenated by an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is currently logged into Facebook, it will display in their localized language.  If not, I believe it defaults to the language you specify in the script file include.